# Select tag not working with submit button in a table

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table that has one `<tr>` and two `<td>` inside of it. The first `<td>` shows a drop-down that has a list of books that the user chooses and the second `<td>` has a button that will trigger a function after choosing a book. The button works fine, but the problem is that it triggers the function even when the option is set to the "Select Book" title while it is supposed to work only when the book name is chosen not the title which asking the user to select a book.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="" style="position:relative" >
        <select id="test">
          <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select Book</option>

          <?php
            //API calls happening to get the list of books
          ?>

          <option value="<?php //echo id of each book; ?>"><?php //echo name of books ?></option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="submit" value="Add to Cart" onclick="addBook()">
    </td>
  </tr>   
</table>
```

here is the javascript I am running on clicking on the button.

```
function addBook() {

        //getting product name and append it in the report table
        var BookName = $("#test option:selected").text();
        var tr = "<tr><td>" + BookName + "</td></tr>";
        $("#SecondTable").append(tr);
    }
```

So as you can see with the above JS, I will also print "Select Book" as it is assuming that "Select Book" is a book name!

Comment: where's your js code???

Comment: @BhojendraSah, please refer to the above JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check first if the option selected is disabled, then attempt to load the view, please check your function i have edited...

```
function addBook() {
//getting product name and append it in the report table
var selectedbook = $("#test option:selected");
if(!selectedbook.is(":disabled"))
{ 
  var BookName = selectedbook.text();
  var tr = "<tr><td>" + BookName + "</td></tr>";
  $("#SecondTable").append(tr);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`<option disabled="disabled">foo</option>` makes it so that value is not selectable. It does not stop you from submitting the form.

If you want to *validate* a form before submitting, write a validation function that you execute in the `onsubmit` of the form. You can find many examples on how to do this if you search for "form validation".

---

Also keep in mind that the disabled option is merely a suggestion. A user of your form can still submit any value they like (even bypass your validation function). Validation *must* take place on the server. Whatever else you do in HTML is *nice to have*.

Comment: can I ask by validation you mean something like an if statement  in JS that checks if the value of selection is not "Select Book" then apply addBook function?